# Car power supply filtering circuit check

Tags: power-supply, power, automotive, filtering

Could someone give me some advice if the power supply filtering on my automotive project is OK? The project will be running in a 12 V car, and pull around 4 to 5 A max.

I have use a PMOSFET for reverse polarity protection.

Would the inductor help with the protection or is it not really required?

The regulator has a max V<sub>in</sub> of 50 V.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please define your Automotive immunity design specs and swap DS . They are reversed for a PFET.

Comment: What the PMOSFET has to do? Why so many MOVs, Varistor, TVSs?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The PFET looks the correct orientation to me...I might be missing something, however.

Comment: What are you hoping the inductor does?

Comment: The PFET source ought to be pointing to the higher voltage side on the left @evildemonic  check again.  Right now it is the Drain to the higher side which you ought to know is reversed

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I am definitely missing something then.  While I agree that the source should point to the higher voltage, I'm having trouble understanding how this would work if reversed.  The body diode would conduct and therefore not provide reverse protection.  Trying to figure this out, google shows me tons of circuits that have the P-MOS installed as drawn (with drain facing the higher voltage).  I am even more confused now.

Comment: That is for reverse protection in bidirection currents. This is unidirectional. How long have you been working in this field?

Comment: 17 years.  Still looking for enlightenment on this issue.  The part he has circled as "reverse polarity protection" looks like the classic circuit to me (p-mos style).

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Can you clarify your statement about unidirectional vs bidirectional?  It has been my understanding that in reverse polarity protection circuits, you need the p-mos in "backwards" otherwise it doesn't do what is advertised.

Comment: try again. I can explain better with a simulation to show why a backwards PMOS conducts thru the body diode and Schottky clamp diode https://tinyurl.com/ydn7aljd when reversed input

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  I think your simulation proves my point.  The top circuit is the way to go.  Are we seeing things backwards from each other somehow?

Comment: I agree . if dyslexia or Murphy's Law strikes me , its the simple things that get me. TY

Comment: Hi all thank you for the comments/help. The idea for the mosfet was from (https://components101.com/articles/design-guide-pmos-mosfet-for-reverse-voltage-polarity-protection), I know i could use a diode but i thought as I would be drawing 4 to 5a this would be best to do. The basic idea for the schematic was from https://forum.pjrc.com/threads/26329-Looking-for-electrical-review-on-my-project?styleid=2 and the inital TVS (ERZ-V20D220) was from the megasquirt schematic v3. The MF-R700 was intended as a resettable fuse, should something go wrong.  Thanks again Trev

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjLjwV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 is the reverse polarity protection, TVS1 is the reverse voltage clamp. TVS2 clamps forward voltage and conducts for reverse voltage to the TVS1.

Comment: This is the preferred solution as you don't need an ideal FET diode for a 3.3V LDO even if it appears to be overkill . as any 1N4005 type would do. No inductance required PTC handles the fault conditions.

Comment: This looks like a RBO40 https://www.st.com/en/protection-devices/rbo40.html , so i guess i could use this along with a PTC and cap and all should be good. Thanks again. Trev